# Maximum update depth exceeded ReactJs componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understood the error, my componentDidUpdate functions is creating an infinite loop, i don't know hot to fix it. I found the two errors that the traceback show me, but i don't know what to do. Here is the submit handler function, it's in the main (logup) component:

```
submitHandler = event => {          
    event.preventDefault();
    const {month, day, year} = this.state.data;
    this.setState({
       loading: true,
       error: false,
       errors: {},
       data: {
          ...this.state.data,
          foundation: `${month} ${day} de ${year}`
       }
    });

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/logup/',
       {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify(this.state.data)
        }).then(response => {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log('redirect to social nets');
            } else {
                this.setState({ error: true });
            }
            return response.json();
        }).then(json => {
            if (this.state.error) {
                this.setState({errors: json}) // The traceback give me error right here
            } else {
                console.log(json);
            }
        });    
    };
```

I also have many Inputs component in the render of that logup component, the traceback show me errors here too.

```
state = {
    error: false
};

componentDidUpdate() {
      let bad = Object.keys(this.context.errors).includes(this.props.name);
      if (bad) {
         this.setState({ error: true }); // traceback give me error too.        
      };
   };
```

[image: Traceback]

[image: error]

Answer (score 2):

In your `componentDidUpdate` you update state in the following manner:

```js
this.setState({ error: true })
```

You do so under the condition that this is true:

```js
Object.keys(this.context.errors).includes(this.props.name)
```

Setting the state causes the component to rerender and also update, so `componentDidUpdate` will run again. However, it is very likely that when that happens your condition above will still be true. You will thus update state again, and React will not short circuit the state update because you are creating a new object every time. One simple way to save yourself here would be to change your condition to:

```
      if (bad && !this.state.error) {
         this.setState({ error: true }); // traceback give me error too.        
      };
```

Comment: Man, i love youuuuuu! that works. I had spend like 5 days in this error and you solved it in minutesssssss! <3

Comment: I'm a professional React developer, if it makes you feel better.

Comment: im 16, i hope to be like you someday. Do you have github repo?

Answer (score 1):

You should use some type of conditions inside `componentDidUpdate` for not to trigger state update. Like thus below:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      let bad = Object.keys(this.context.errors).includes(this.props.name);
      if (prevState.error !== this.state.error && bad) {
         this.setState({ error: true }); // traceback give me error too.        
      };
   };
```

Always compare the prevState and currentState value inside `componentDidUpdate` as in most cases this condition is suffice.

> **Note :** Before starts using `componentDidUpdate` please refer to the docs as it also provides `prevProps` and `prevState` values which
> are always helpful in such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (bad) {
    this.setState({ error: true }); // traceback give me error too.        
};
```

to

```
if (bad && !this.state.error) {
    this.setState({ error: true }); // traceback give me error too.        
};
```

Using `setState` inside of `componentDidUpdate` will cause it to re-render and recall `componentDidUpdate`. Adding an additional check will help stop this loop.